# 7.4 Volts DC to 3-4 volts (small application)

Tags: voltage

I'm using a 7.4-volt battery, I need to drop the voltage to somewhere between 3 and 4 volts. It is for a relatively small application so the smaller the better. My amperage needs to stay the same.

It's 1500 mah

[Battery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N16LO3R)

Comment: What amperage do you need? Please specify. It matters for the solution.

Comment: @Huisman I'm not sure I just don't want it to change. Its 1500 mah.

Comment: This is really not answerable without more specifics.  The simple, cheap, inefficient but quiet way is with a linear regulator.  While a switching regulator done right will be more efficient, but at the expense of increased cost and introducing noise which may cause radio or analog interference and take effort to counteract.  And of course you can't select either without having an idea of the current requirement.  Also bear in mind that your "7.4-volt battery" probably ranged from 8.4 volts down to 6 volts or even less if it is heavily loaded late in discharge.

Comment: "1500 mah" is a *capacity* rating not a current rating, and even a current rating of a supply wouldn't indicate what your device actually draws, only put a degree of upper bound on it.

Comment: Have you considered using a single cell rather than two in series?  If your application can tolerate up to 4.2v (or a little more for some batteries/charger) that might avoid the regulator all together.

Comment: @JMP: Welcome to EE.SE but you need to be more specific about what you are asking. You haven't actually asked a question. Read the comments carefully and try to fix your question to address all the points raised.

Comment: @Transistor I'm sorry, I'm new to this format. I'll definitely work on it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Dropping voltage is the job of a **buck regulator**, **linear (low-dropout or LDO) regulator**, or various less-common methods such as a resistor divider, etc.

You cannot drop the voltage across a given load *and* maintain the same current through it. Voltage and current together define the quantity of power (watts) that is being delivered:

$$P = IE$$

From this (part of Ohm's Law), you can see that as you vary the voltage (E), you *inversely* must vary current (I) to maintain power (P).

A simple example: If you have 10 volts with a maximum current of 1 amp, you can use an ideal (non-existent) buck regulator to convert it to, say, 5 volts with a maximum current of 2 amps. In the real world, all conversions have losses, so you would more likely see 5 volts at perhaps 1.7 amps or so (85% efficient).

Your battery capacity is rated in milliamp-hours, which is a current-over-time sort of unit, specifying how long the battery can deliver a given current. There are plenty of other questions which discuss this. Again, a "perfect" battery with 1500 mAh rating could deliver 1.5 amps for 1 hour, or 3 amps for 0.5 hours, etc. Again, in the real world, batteries have internal resistance, and a myriad of nonlinear performance characteristics resulting from their varied chemistry.

Not only that, but battery datasheets will show you derating charts which give *different* mAh capacities based on the current they are supplying:

[image: Battery derating chart]

This means that a 1500 mAh battery might supply 50mA for ~30 hours, but get nowhere close to the 1 hour if supplying 1.5A.

It's critical (as comments have pointed out) that you know the requirements for the device you want to power at the lower voltage. You can then figure what sort of regulator will do the job (amount of power it can handle, efficiency requirement, and so on).

Hopefully this will help you out, and know what to search for. If you have additional questions, search first, then feel free to ask a new question (as a new post).